# logrotate seems work incorrect

Tags: logrotate

I'm using:
Linux workdesk 3.16.0-31-generic #43~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 10 20:13:38 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

logrotate 3.8.7-1ubuntu1 amd64

I trying to test behaviour of logrotate.

my conf file is:

```
/home/user/test/*.log {  
       daily  
       rotate 2  
       ifempty  
       su user user  
}
```

`ls /home/user/test/*.log` outputs

```
/home/user/test/1.log
```

`sudo logrotate -fv /etc/logrotate.d/r`

outputs

```
reading config file /etc/logrotate.d/r

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /home/user/test/*.log  forced from command line (2 rotations)  
empty log files are rotated, old logs are removed  
switching euid to 1000 and egid to 1000  
considering log /home/user/test/1.log  
  log needs rotating  
rotating log /home/user/test/1.log, log->rotateCount is 2  
dateext suffix '-20150327'  
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'  
renaming /home/user/test/1.log.2 to /home/user/test/1.log.3 (rotatecount 2, logstart 1, i 2),  
old log /home/user/test/1.log.2 does not exist  
renaming /home/user/test/1.log.1 to /home/user/test/1.log.2 (rotatecount 2, logstart 1, i 1),  
old log /home/user/test/1.log.1 does not exist  
renaming /home/user/test/1.log.0 to /home/user/test/1.log.1 (rotatecount 2, logstart 1, i 0),  
old log /home/user/test/1.log.0 does not exist  
log /home/user/test/1.log.3 doesn't exist -- won't try to dispose of it  
renaming /home/user/test/1.log to /home/user/test/1.log.1  
switching euid to 0 and egid to 0
```

and after `ls` outputs

```
1.log.1
```

and that's all

Can somebody explain the rotation of process?
1) What is "renaming /home/user/test/1.log.0 to /home/user/test/1.log.1"? If I have rotate count = 0
2) Where is 1.log file?
3) where is 1.log.0? As I understand it I should get only 1.log empty file and that's all

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration file asks to rotate file `*.log` in `/home/user/test` every day even if file is empty and preserve two old file.

[logrotate](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/logrotate.8.html) perform this action (as you can see in verbose output):

- change user and group (due to `su user user`)
- rename old logs if exist, starting from `1.log.2` (due to `rotate 2`)
- remove `1.log.3` if exists (due to `rotate 2`)
- rename current `1.log` in `1.log.1`
- switch back user and group

So, as expected, at the end you found `1.log.1` that it should be `1.log` file renamed.

Rename process prints error, but logrotate doesn't fail, if old log file doesn't exist, which hasn't been created yet in previous days.

If an application is writing in `1.log`, after log rotation, it still writing in `1.log.1` because renaming file doesn't change file's inode.
In this case you should force application to close current log file and reopen it, using its graceful restart.

Here is a useful [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598318/can-logrotate-suffer-race-conditions/598716#598716) on how to do.

I'm not able to explain why logrotate tries to rename `1.log.0`, it seems an implementation error that don't cause any bug.